# Maintaining mongodb for a huge list of message "documents"?

Tags: performance, mongodb, management

**Intro:**

I am working on an app right now for live messaging and it's almost complete. The database strategy is in order. So when a new message is created it is sent as an object fitting my mongoDB model, nice.

---

**Theory:**

I am no expert (obviously), but I have a few things in mind. One, somehow limit the list of documents to maybe 1,000 and export the rest somewhere (not a million dollar idea, but just brainstorming). That's really it lol!

---

**Question:**

So I am asking what is the best way to manage a huge list of documents, most at the tail end never being needed (just saved to go back on some conversations). Thinking about it most old messages when you scroll far up (skype, text, etc) disappear after awhile. So I am thinking my theory isn't so bad?

Is there a standard for handling a huge list? Should I just leave it alone, I feel like it would become hard to manage?

Answer (score 2):

A [capped collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/) would allow you to maintain a relatively small list, though you would want to have a decent buffer, or be very confident in terms of the size of your documents.  The other option would be a [TTL collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/), but that would be more prone to fragmentation since it will be doing a lot of deletes (this will mean having to deal with said fragmentation regularly with [repair](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase/), [compact](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/compact/) or a [resync](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/)).

Based on what you outline, this sounds very like what people have done when looking to implement a message queue with MongoDB - you use the capped or TTL collection for your immediate needs, then you decide what level of durability you want for the documents long term. That is, store them in another collection, database, or even another instance of MongoDB entirely before they are removed.  At a larger scale I have even seen people have long term and short term shards, but that should be a long way down the line from your initial attempts.

If you do go down the path of a capped collection, with "long term" storage elsewhere, it is often beneficial to have the capped collection on one disk and the other data elsewhere (capped collections tend to have sequential access patterns, whereas regular collections tend towards random access).  That means using different databases, different disk mount points, and the [directoryperdb](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#directoryperdb) option.

There are a lot of potential options here but thankfully several of the approaches have been publicised and documented.  To start I would take a look at these:

http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/mongodb-message-queue
http://captaincodeman.com/2011/05/28/simple-service-bus-message-queue-mongodb/
http://blog.mongodb.org/post/29495793738/pub-sub-with-mongodb

Hopefully that's enough to get you started.

Comment: That's exactly what I need, thanks! I just wanted to be assured that my idea of maintaining the database was actually a good idea, because I want to prepare ahead of time before the collection gets big and hard to manage. There are definitely some new terms I need to learn, but your overall answer makes sense. Doing it hands on is a whole different thing, hopefully I catch onto it soon.

Comment: The capped collection+"long term storage elsewhere" is an interesting approach.